# delphi dataset clear datetime field

Tags: delphi

Though I can set current date with :

> DataSet['MY_DATE'] := Now;

it's unclear to me how to clear this field. I tried:

> DataSet['MY_DATE'] :=''

But it wont work. Any suggestion ? DB is SQLite.

The entire code how this is used :

```
procedure TDataModule1.SAL_TWITTERBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if SAL_TWITTER.FieldByName('managed').AsBoolean = True then begin
DataSet['UREDIL'] := UNIQuery4.FieldByName('sotrpin').AsString;
DataSet['UREJENO_KDAJ'] :=Now;
end else
DataSet['UREDIL'] := '';
//DataSet.FieldByName('UREJENO_KDAJ').Clear; <----- does not work
end;
```

Comment: Try DataSet.FieldByName('MY_DATE').Clear;

Comment: "it wont work" is not a useful problem description. In what way does it not work? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime error? Something else? You know what "it wont work" means, and it's useful if you provide that information to us as well. We can't see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: The field does not get cleared. And that is what I am trying to do.  'It does not work' applies to that.

Comment: Everything works except the part where my DateTime field 'UREJENO_KDAJ' should get cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, an empty string doesn't represent a date to which the field can be set.

In particular, TDataSets do not treat it as equivalent to setting the database field to Null, which is what people usually mean when they refer to "clearing" a field.

Instead do:

```
  DataSet.FieldByName('MY_DATE').Clear;
```

Comment: I seems I had to change the field properties in the cxgrid for that datetime field in order for this answer to work.Thank you all...

Comment: I confess I'm slightly puzzled why any properties in your cxGrid should affect the clearing of datetime fields in code, but I don't have a recent version of it to investigate with.  If you're puzzled about that too, your best bet might be to ask the Developer Express support people direct through their usual support channels.